# how to reference a button value to a HREF attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html and Javascript world.

I want a dynamic href link which updates based on the value of a button.

```
<button value="deletemiv?mav={{majorID}}" id="deleteID">
<a href="how to reference?">
```

I want to reference this value inside a href attribute. how to do it?

Comment: Please provided additional context and attempts you've made to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about this would be to set an ID on both elements. You can then use `document.getElementByID` to both build a JavaScript variable that houses the button, and also set the `href` attribute of the hyperlink:

```js
var the_button = document.getElementById("button_id");
document.getElementById("link").href = the_button.value;
```

```html
<button value="deletemiv?mav={{majorID}}" id="button_id">
<a id="link" href="#">Delete</a>
```

In the above example, the link from the hyperlink is set to the `value` of the button, `deletemiv?mav={{majorID}}`.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add Jquery to your page by including the lib in the head of your html page

then below it include a javascript file with the dom ready function

bind a click event listener to the button then just use jquery to set the attr of the href so

$('#link').attr('href','your link here');

place that above line inside the click listener function